# Facebook Messenger Bot sending repeated request after adding getstarted button

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hi i have set up a get started Button in fb messenger Bot and sending userdefined payload and in backend when i am getting this event payload i am sending buttons in quick replies.After selecting the button again facebook is sending the request again and i am getting two buttons again.After selecting buttons i am sending postback payload and handling the payload,but from facebook i am getting repeated requests which are some time delivery acknowledgements response.

Can any body help what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you selected under your Webhooks/Edit events?
If you are getting repeated requests, you may want to try by simply selecting messages and messaging_postbacks and try again.
You will eventually need to handle messaging_policy_enforcement, when you want to get you bot approved, but for now only these two events will do for most entry level chatbots. 
Another approach for now, is to ignore all events with no message.text or message.attachment or message.postback. Something like this in java script:

```
  if (event && event.message && 
      !(event.message.text || 
        event.message.attachments ||
        event.message.postback ) ) {
           // at this time -  don't process anything other than text, 
           //attachments or postbacks - so ignore everything else
   } else {
     // do your normal processing 
   }
```